# jquery fadein a div created on the fly

Tags: jquery, html, css

This question is asked many times but I have a different detail. Would you please help me append a div which is created on the fly? But the difference is I have to create the div like below.

here is the Jquery

```
 var new_div = "<div class='rounded_corner_with_border_and_tag' style='line-height:35px'><span class='span_tags'>Temel Bilgiler</span><br /><br /><div style='float:left;width:130px'>İsim:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text1' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='float:left;width:130px'>Soyad:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text2' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='float:left;width:130px'>Ünvan:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text3' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='float:left;width:130px'>Uzmanlık:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text4' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='float:left;width:130px'>Cep Numarası:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text5' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='line-height:6px'>&nbsp;</div><div style='float:right'><input type='button' id='Button2' name='btn_new_photo' value='Güncelle' class='theme05' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div></div>";
```

I cannot create a static div, so I have to create it div in javascript above.

here is my simple jquery code....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#menu_1').click(function () {
            var new_div = "<div class='rounded_corner_with_border_and_tag' style='line-height:35px'><span class='span_tags'>Temel Bilgiler</span><br /><br /><div style='float:left;width:130px'>İsim:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text1' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='float:left;width:130px'>Soyad:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text2' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='float:left;width:130px'>Ünvan:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text3' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='float:left;width:130px'>Uzmanlık:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text4' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='float:left;width:130px'>Cep Numarası:</div><div style='float:left;width:200px'><input id='Text5' class='blue_input' type='text' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div><div style='line-height:6px'>&nbsp;</div><div style='float:right'><input type='button' id='Button2' name='btn_new_photo' value='Güncelle' class='theme05' /></div><div style='clear:both'></div></div>";

            $('#div_profile_container').append(new_div).fadein();
        });
    });
```

I need to make div display:none first then fade in but couldnt do it. Please help...

Comment: Is `#div_profile_container` visible?  The method is `.fadeIn`, not `.fadein`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.hide()` after `.append(new_div)`

```
$('#div_profile_container').append(new_div).hide().fadeIn();
```

Also, as Explosion Pills mentioned, the method is `fadeIn` (capital I), not `fadein`.

Or, you could simply alter your style declaration and make it `style='line-height:35px; display: none;'`

Comment: What exactly is happening? Nothing? Something else popping up? is an error being thrown in a console?

Comment: I made div like this <div class='rounded_corner_with_border_and_tag' style='line-height:35px;display: none;'> ..... then I changed my jquery to this $('#div_profile_container').append(new_div).fadeIn();   and now nothing shows up. it doesnt show error either

Comment: Remove the `display:none;`, and is `#div_profile_container` visible?

Comment: but if I remove display:none , then it doesnt do the fadein animation

Comment: well, it seems to work but it makes hidden all divs and fade them in again. bu I wanted to fade in only the newly added div

Answer (score 1):

The approach I always use (instead of first using .hide() ) is to simply flag the "display" property as "none" when building the element. For example:

```
<div class='rounded_corner_with_border_and_tag' style='line-height:35px; display:none;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it at last. thanks for your help. I gave an Id to div and made it hidden

```
var new_div = "<br /><div id='div_menu_1' class='rounded_corner_with_border_and_tag' style='line-height:35px;display:none'>"
```

then, I append it to div and made it fadeIn with jquery below

```
$('#div_profile_container').append(new_div);
$('#div_menu_1').fadeIn();
```